# To get current time

Tags: custom-field

I have a number formula field. It should display current time in hh.mm format. I am writing Date/Time functions but it doesn't seem to work. Please provide solution for this.

Comment: Why return a Number instead of a Date/Time?

Comment: If you want help with a formula field it is best to include what you have so far so that it is possible to say what you are doing wrong.

Comment: There is a similar post for the solution I think you are seeking.Can you check this and see if it helps you?

http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42626/how-to-extract-the-time-into-a-formula-field

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final formula:

```
DATETIMEVALUE(TEXT(YEAR(Start_Date__c))+"-" +TEXT(MONTH(Start_Date__c))+"-" +TEXT(DAY(Start_Date__c))+" "+TEXT(VALUE(LEFT(Start_Time__c, 2))+ 7)+  MID(Start_Time__c,3,3)+":00")﻿
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Text formula field and below definition -

```
MID(TEXT(NOW()),12,5)
```