# How to remove AM & PM from Time field?

Tags: configuration, time

I have a custom field with DataType is TIME. I want to remove AM and PM from the Field. How can I do this?

Comment: This link may help you https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42626/how-to-extract-the-time-into-a-formula-field

Comment: Are you trying to use 24 hour notation instead?

Comment: I want it in LEX without changing any Locale....in just format of HH:MM

Answer (score 1):

In the classic mode:

**for the Orgenaization Level**

Click on setup > search for Company Information > click edit

than change the `Default Locale` to "English(United Kingdom)" or select form given reference 2

this will make organisation level change.

**For the particular User:**

Edit the user and than change `Locale` to "English(United Kingdom)" or select form given reference 2

[image]

Referance links1:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_field_time_overview.htm&type=5

Referance links2:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_supported_locales.htm&type=5

Comment: Is there any solution without changing Locale of user in LEX ... I want in format of HH:MM .

Comment: Salesforce Classic: A time field displays a value based on your organization’s Locale setting on the Company Information page in Setup or using changing the user locale. See Supported Locales in Salesforce Help for each locale’s display Time Format.
But here is the Alternate that will work for but need to create formula field.
In formulas, get a time value from the TIMEVALUE function. Use TIMENOW, HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND, and MILLISECOND functions with time in formulas.

Comment: NOTE In formula expressions, use the international date format (ISO) for text arguments. For example, use TIMEVALUE("11:30:00.000") instead of TIMEVALUE("11:30 AM").

Answer (score 0):

create formula field and Use LEFT(RIGHT(text( field name ),12),5)