# Datetime field value as fomatted text in event's description using process builder

Tags: process-builder, formula-field

we have process builder, that creates an event. on event we have description field which we want to add some textual detail with datetime field value.

see below Example

`datetime field value :  7/11/2021 2:05 AM`

Expecting
Event description as : `This event should be completed prior to  7/11/2021 2:05 AM`

Currently what we are getting
Event description as : `This event should be completed prior to  2021-07-11 09:05:00Z`

Comment: when generating a text version of a date inside a String field, you need to decide what timezone to use --  as _all users will see the text as a constant, regardless of what timezone the user is sitting in_.  So, it is important that the representation include the TZ. What TZ do you want to show?

Comment: @cropredy i am looking for (GMT-05:00) Central Daylight Time (America/Mexico_City).

Comment: this problem is challenging because of DST -- see [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/46467/2602) and adapt based on this [forum post](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000g983QAA). Personally, I'd escape to apex to do this as the formulas tend to be obtuse and hard to follow